# Is Azure AD B2C with Azure AD Domain Services possible?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, tableau-api

I am working on setting up Tableau server. I want end users who login with their Azure AD B2C credentials to see some of the visualizations we build in Tableau.

While setting up Tableau, I noticed that Tableau works with Azure AD Domain services only. Two of our user groups in Azure AD is synched with ADDS. So I am able to add those users to Tableau.

However, I do not see similar synchronization option between ADDS and AD B2C.

Question: ADDS is only for Azure AD and not for AD B2C? Any suggestions to achieve my goal mentioned in first two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official documentation

Azure Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) provides managed domain services such as domain join, group policy, lightweight directory access protocol (LDAP), and Kerberos/NTLM authentication. You use these domain services without the need to deploy, manage, and patch domain controllers (DCs) in the cloud.

it is meant as a mean to help customer that are using active directory on premise to migrate their domain controllers to Azure domain services and still support authentication and traditional management using OU, LDAPS and Kerberos.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#:~:text=Azure%20Active%20Directory%20Domain%20Services%20(AD%20DS)%20provides%20managed%20domain,(DCs)%20in%20the%20cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#:%7E:text=Azure%20Active%20Directory%20Domain%20Services%20(AD%20DS)%20provides%20managed%20domain,(DCs)%20in%20the%20cloud)

Azure B2C

Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) is an identity management service that enables custom control of how your customers sign up, sign in, and manage their profiles when using your iOS, Android, .NET, single-page (SPA), and other applications.

basically this is meant to support modern authentication for applications using OIDS,OAuth2, SAML

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/#:~:text=Azure%20Active%20Directory%20B2C%20(Azure,SPA)%2C%20and%20other%20applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/#:%7E:text=Azure%20Active%20Directory%20B2C%20(Azure,SPA)%2C%20and%20other%20applications).

so you cannot use AADS (Active Directory) to manage B2C authentications.

to configure Tableau with Azure Active Directory I suggest you use SAML as described in official documentation:

Tableau SAML
https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/saml.htm

Azure B2C SAML
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers

you should have something like the below

[image]

1. User navigates to the Tableau Server sign-in page or clicks a published workbook URL.
2. Tableau Server starts the authentication process by redirecting the client to the configured IdP (Azure B2C).
3. Azure B2C requests the user’s username and password from the user. After the user submits valid credentials, Azure B2C authenticates the user.
4. Azure B2C returns the successful authentication in the form of a SAML Response to the client. The client passes the SAML Response to Tableau Server.

5.Tableau Server verifies that the username in the SAML Response matches a licensed user stored in the Tableau Server Repository. If a match is verified, then Tableau Server responds to the client with the requested content

Comment: Thanks Anass. One more question. My frontend application is already configured to use Azure AD B2C for login. If I configure Tableau to use same as IdP, can user do single sign on? Example: user logs in to frontend application using AD B2C, clicks on a link and it opens tableau url without asking them to login and taking the credentials of frontend application

Comment: if the user is already authenticated using B2C using SAML normally he/she will not be asked if the front end is configured correctly that is the point of using SAML to achieve SSO and b2C as an IdP

Comment: @JapEvans does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you @Anass